# Arch Linux Installation EFI partition?

Tags: boot, arch-linux

I am trying to install arch Linux but I got stuck at this step:

```
bootctl install
```

I get :

```
Couldn't find EFI system partition. It is recommended to mount it to /boot. Alternatively, use --path= to specify path to mount point.
```

I saw another question like this. And it seems that as I am in the same position as him. My windows installation was made on BIOS, even though my motherboard supports EFI.
Is there any way to revert into BIOS/legacy mid installation?

Thanks in advance, all help appreciated.

Comment: Which was the other question?

Comment: @8bittree only one question. Is it possible to change from EFI to BIOS even though I am already through installations?

Comment: No, I'm referring to the other question you saw like this.

Comment: @8bittree https://superuser.com/questions/912417/i-wanted-to-install-arch-linux-on-a-uefi-gpt-system-and-had-questions-about-the

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same issue installing Arch Linux.

In my case, it was caused by wrong partition type.
I solved it by changing EFI partition type (/dev/sda1) to "EFI System" using `cfdisk /dev/sda`